# Pandas: How to groupby and get a count of uniques in a given column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a DataFrame that has three columns:

```
id     order     ordernumber  
1      app         1
1      pip         2
1      org         3
2      app         1
3      app         1
3      org         3
```

The "order" column only has 3 unique values (app, pip and org). I would like to get a DataFrame that shows, for each id, how many orders they had of each kind, as well as the number of their total orders.

The result would look like this:

```
id     app        pip    org    total
1      1           1      1      3
2      1           0      0      1
3      1           0      1      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` to get the counts:

```
>>> df2 = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='order', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
>>> df2
order  app  org  pip
id
1        1    1    1
2        1    0    0
3        1    1    0
```

Then you can add the 'total' column by summing each row:

```
>>> df2['total'] = df2.sum(axis=1)
>>> df2
order  app  org  pip  total
id
1        1    1    1      3
2        1    0    0      1
3        1    1    0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to ajcr:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='order', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()), margins=True)
```

Uses a different `aggfunc` to count the uniques.

```
In [4]: df2 = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='order', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()), margins=True)

In [5]: df2
Out[5]:
      ordernum
order      app org pip All
id
1            1   1   1   3
2            1 NaN NaN   1
3            1   1 NaN   2
All          1   1   1   3
```

Also you can use `margins` param to automatically get column/row subtotals for `pivot_table` function.

If you need to replace `NaN` afterward you can use:
`df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)`

```
In [6]: df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
      ordernum
order      app org pip All
id
1            1   1   1   3
2            1   0   0   1
3            1   1   0   2
All          1   1   1   3
```